# How to access the value of a json array in AJAX response

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Right now in my AJAX call I send a json array and, I'm getting a json encoded array back from the server.  This is functioning correctly, as I can verify the values in dev tools.  What I want to add is a conditional block to check the value of response.remaining.  If the value is a negative number, then display it one way, if its positive, display it another way, and if else, just display $0.00.  Something like this:

```
request.done(function(response){
    if(response.remaining.value() < 0){
         $('#remaining').html('<h1 class="negativeNum">&#36;' + response.remaining + '</h1>');
    } else if(response.remaining.value() > 0) {
        $('#remaining').html('<h1 class="positiveNum">&#36;' + response.remaining + '</h1>');
    } else {
        $('#remaining').html('<h1>&#36;0.00</h1>');
    };
});
```

Comment: Please show your JSON response, otherwise it would be hard to figure it out; anyways if you have `{ response : { remaining: someVal }}`, `response.remaining` will do.

Comment: response.remaining.value() , this seems to be wrong, i guess it should be as @moonwave99 suggests

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I may have to go back and look at response.remaining.value().  It wasn't working when I tried it before, but maybe something else is going on.

Comment: this is my json response: {"income":"5,713.75","expense":"555.00","remaining":"5,158.75","perecnt":"0.097134106322468"}

Comment: i'm trying to access the value of "remaining" and compare it to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ultimately worked for me, and honestly, the link marked as duplicate really didn't help me at all.  Maybe this one will help someone else in the future.

```
request.done(function(response) {
    var remaining = response.remaining;
    if(remaining > "0") {
        $('#cash_remaining').html('<h1 class="positiveNum float-right">&#36;' + response.remaining + '</h1>');
    } else if(remaining < "0") {
        $('#cash_remaining').html('<h1 class="negativeNum float-right">&#36;(' + response.remaining + ')</h1>');
    } else {
        $('#cash_remaining').html('<h1 class="float-right">&#36;0.00</h1>');
    };
});
```